# Python 3.x - How do you take an integer variable and convert it to a number of inputs?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, input, integer

So let's suppose that you have a code like this:

```
shape= int(input("How many sides are in your shape?: "))
print("So you have", shape,"number of sides.")
```

Now what I want to do is to take what ever the user inputs (integer of course) and create a number of inputs depending on what the user just inputted. Something like this:

```
>>>
How many sides are in your shape?: 3
So you have 3 number of sides.
What is the 1st letter in your shape's name?: A 
# 'That is an input that I cannot figure out'
What is the 2nd letter in your shape's name?: B 
# 'That is an input that I cannot figure out'
What is the 3rd letter in your shape's name?: C
# 'That is an input that I cannot figure out'
So your shape's name is ABC.
```

Furthermore if the 'shape' variable where to change the number of inputs change as well. So:

```
>>>
How many sides are in your shape?: 5
So you have 3 number of sides.
What is the 1st letter in your shape's name?: E
# 'That is an input that I cannot figure out'
What is the 2nd letter in your shape's name?: F
# 'That is an input that I cannot figure out'
What is the 3rd letter in your shape's name?: H
# 'That is an input that I cannot figure out'
What is the 4th letter in your shape's name?: G
# 'That is an input that I cannot figure out'
So your shape's name is EFHG.
```

Comment: the construct `for _ in range(X):` will loop over the enclosed block `X` times. Hopefully that helps, because I don't otherwise understand your example (your second code block indicates there should be 5 prompts, but then only prompts 4 times...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the ordinal is important to the output ("1st letter", "2nd letter", "3rd letter" etc) then I'd do:

```
def to_ordinal(n:int) -> str:
    """takes a number and returns its ordinal

    >>> to_ordinal(1)
    1st
    >>> to_ordinal(155)
    155th
    """

    endings = {1: "st", 2: "nd", 3: "rd"}

    if 11 <= n < 20:
        return str(n) + "th"
    else:
        return str(n) + endings.get(n % 10, "th")
```

Then wrap the inputs in a `for` loop with an accumulator list.

```
inputs = []
num_inputs = int(input("How many sides? "))
for n in range(1, num_inputs+1):
    inputs.append(f"Name your {to_ordinal(n)} side: ")
    # the f"{some_var}" syntax only works in py3.6+
    # otherwise use `inputs.append("Name your {} side: ".format(to_ordinal(n))`
```

Comment: @fuzzything44 thanks for edit. Looks like we both missed some edge cases (your code caught "22nd" but improperly gave "12nd.") I think my current edit is right.

Comment: I get this error for some reason: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "---------------------------", line 19, in <module>
    for n in range(1, num_inputs+1):
TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: @ObGamErOGE oh 'cuz I'm dumb and didn't cast the user input to int :)

Answer (score 0):

Use shape to iterate through and append to a string.

```
# Create an empty string.
name = ""
# For indices 0 through the length of shape minus 1,
for i in range(shape):
    # request user input for that index and add the letter inputted to the end of the string.
    name = name + input("Input letter %d: " % i)
# Then print the string.
print("\nYour shape's name is " + name + ".")
```

Comment: Out of curiosity -- why use a string for this?

Comment: @AdamSmith I interpreted the question to mean that #ObGamErOGE cares about the user inputs getting appended together into a name.  Your code works great for generating the inputs to the input function (the prompt).  Using both code snippets #ObGamErOGE should be able to accomplish their goal.

Comment: Fair enough! Word to the wise: string concatenation is very inefficient. If `shape` gets very large, that might cause issues. If you accumulate into a list then use `''.join(that_list)` you get the same output for much cheaper.

Comment: How did you do that. I mean it works perfectly but I do not understand why. Can any one explain to me how it works please.

Comment: I've edited the code to have comments explaining how it works.  Let me know if there is anything that doesn't make sense and I'll explain it for you.  Also, you may want to change the `i` in the argument of `input()` to `(i+1)` if you want it to start at `1` instead of at `0`.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

So what I ended up doing is using @cameronroytaylor and @AdamSmith's responses to create this code.

```
shape= int(input("How many sides are in your shape?: "))
print("So you have", shape,"number of sides.")
```

and then added this:

```
num = 0

looper = shape+1

name = ""

for n in range(looper):
    num += 1
    def to_ordinal(n:int) -> str:

        endings = {1: "st", 2: "nd", 3: "rd"}

        if 11 <= n < 20:
            return str(n) + "th"
        else:
            return str(n) + endings.get(n % 10, "th")

    if num > 1:
        name = name + input(f"What is the {to_ordinal(n)} letter in your first shape's name?: ")
    # the f"{some_var}" syntax only works in py3.6+
    # otherwise use `inputs.append("Name your {} side: ".format(to_ordinal(n))`

print("\nYour first", shape+"'s name is " + name + ".")
```

Please Check @cameronroytaylor and @AdamSmith's responses because they helped come up with these answers. They deserve the credit.